# Removing <p><br/></p> tag from starting and ending of a content in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a javascript regex through which I could remove the `<p><br><p>` tag from my content.

for example:

Below one is my content

```
<p><br></p>
<p>function removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string.</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br/><p>
```

and I am looking for this

`<p>function removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string.</p>`

I am using  this code but it is not working

```
function rtrim(str) {
  if(!str) return str;
  return str.replace(/\s+$/g, '');
}

console.log(rtrim(string));
```

Comment: Do you want to remove `<p><br></p>` or `<p><br/><p>` or `<p><br><p>`? ;) They're all different, and you need to be quite specific with regex

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher Hi, I am trying to remove ```<p><br></p>``` only from the starting and ending of the contents.

Comment: Is it required that you use a RegExp? Or is it ok to split and filter the string?

Comment: Ok, so you don't care about `<br>` vs `<br/>`?
Also when you say "from the starting and ending of the contents", you mean you only care to remove it from the first line and last line? Or you want to remove it anywhere it shows up in the entire content?

Comment: any number of  ```<p><br><p>``` s  from starting and ending

Answer (score 3):

You want to remove the HTML Linebreaks `<br/>` and its surrounding paragraph element `<p>` and not whitespaces, which you do with your current regex.

> **\s+** matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

This should be the correct regex in your case `<p><br[\/]?><[\/]?p>`

```js
function rtrim(str) {
  if(!str) return str;
  return str.replace(/<p><br[\/]?><[\/]?p>/g, '');
}

console.log(rtrim("<p><br></p><p>function removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string.</p><p><br></p><p><br/><p>"));
```

I used `<br[\/]?>` to make sure both linebreaks with and without a forward slash will match.

Comment: Thanks for this - it helps with Quill editor that has stray paragraphs and line-breaks when it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of replacing `<p><br></p>`, You can extract only `<p>some text</p>`.

For example like below,

```
let a = "<p><br></p><p>function removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string.</p><p><br></p><p><br/><p>";
a = /(<p>[^<>].*[^<>]<\/p>)/g.exec(a)[0];
console.log(a); // "<p>function removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string.</p>"
```

Comment: +1 It will work, but only if its content is always inside a <p> tag. It could be solved with this  regex: `/(<[a-z\-]+>[^<>].*[^<>]<\/[a-z\-]+>)/`

Answer (score 1):

If you need specifically a RegExp I would suggest the answer posted by **Red**.

If you are not required to use a RegExp, you could split by line and filter that string, then join it again,
*although this example will only work if they are separated by `\n`*:

```js
function rtrim(str) {
  if(!str) return str;
  return str
    .split('\n')
    .filter((s) => s === '<p><br></p>')
    .join('\n');
}
```